# Cisco show logging command filtered by specific date

Tags: router

Is there a way to filter the output of a Cisco `show logging` command to only show entries from a specific date? I can get logs for a specific interface with the following command:

```
show logging | i 3/1/0.6/3:0
```

However, I would like to filter it further by specific date. Here is an example of the show logging output:

```
Oct 30 20:44:42.941 UTC: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial3/1/0.6/3:0, changed state to down
```

Comment: When you want to start doing this sort of thing, it's time to set up a syslog server to capture the logs and manipulate the captured data.

Answer (score 1):

To filter on date you can use as well the include as you suggested for the interface.
You just need to use parenthesis to delimit the sting:

```
show logging | include (Oct 30 20:44)..*(3/1/0.6/3:0)
```

Comment: I think i tried this already and it would bring up other interfaces. Could i do the following?








show logging | i 3/1/0.6/3:0 | include (Oct 30 20:44)

Comment: Correction:
show logging | include (Oct 30 20:44)..*(3/1/0.6/3:0)

Comment: Did the command I have provided work?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you so much. Sorry for my delayed response. You have saved me a lot of time.